# Only register events once

Tags: javascript, ajax, event-handling, dom-events

I wrote a small script to load pages with ajax. All links that have the `ajax-pls`- class, should be selected.

After I add the `eventlistener` I remove the class, because I need to parse the included html every time.... right?

```
(function() {
    function addEvent(element, evnt, funct){
    if (element.attachEvent)
        return element.attachEvent('on'+evnt, funct);
    else
        return element.addEventListener(evnt, funct, false);
    }
  
  var link_click = function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      if (this.getAttribute("href") == 'test1.html') {
        var content = document.getElementById('content');
        content.innerHTML = "<a href='test3.html' class='ajax-pls'>Test3</a>";
        register_listeners();
      } else {
        alert(this);
      }
    };
  
  function register_listeners() {
     
    var atags = document.querySelectorAll('a.ajax-pls');
    for (i = 0; i < atags.length; i++) {
      addEvent(atags[i], 'click', link_click);
      atags[i].classList.remove("ajax-pls");
    }
  }
  
  register_listeners();
})();
```

It is just test-code, but do I need to do the trick with the class or could I just call `register_listeners()` after every include?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you need to remove classes otherwise, `addEvent` will add same handler several times to each link.

But you can bypass this issue by using event bubbling.

If you add handler to nearest common ancestor of every link (in worst case it would be `document.body`). It will catch every click event on  every elements inside it. You will need to filter them by checking  `event.target`.